# Does firebase/GA4 data change in Bigquery retrospectively

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-4, dbt

I am setting up right now GA4/Firebase in BigQuery and use [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/) on top of it for analytics.
Since the data of those 2 source is quite large, I want to activate incremental load and only update my analytic models for today + yesterday (instead of doing a full refresh of all the data each time).

Here is now where I am not sure: Can GA4/Firebase data change retrospectively? And if yes, how many hours/days?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Analytics data is only sent from Firebase to BigQuery from the moment you enable the integration. No historical data from before this moment is exported.

Comment: But can data, that was sent from firebase/ga4 to bigquery, still change afterwards? 
I dont know, maybe GA4 did not parse all event_params data correctly in the moment the event was sent to Bigquery and changes a couple of seconds later. Can the same event log / row change afterwards?

Okay maybe simpler: is the way data from GA4/firebase moves an insert or an upsert?

Comment: I don't think events ever change. As far as I understand, they're an append-only data structure.

Comment: thanks, makes sense.
A colleague just mentions that firebase has a 72 (? cant find documentation about that) hours catchup mechanism if an app was used offline.
Does that sound familiar to you or do you maybe even have a source for that? :)

Comment: This is the first I could quickly find: https://youtu.be/XrltP8bOHT0?t=1280